# Cannot set session cookie from express app into vue 3 application using axios

Tags: node.js, express, axios, vuejs3, session-cookies

**Link to Backend repo:** https://github.com/abeertech01/session-cookies-express

**Link to Frontend repo:** https://github.com/abeertech01/session-cookies-vue3

**Steps to reproduce:**

- Download and `npm i` repos
- Run `npm run dev` for both repos
- Navigate to: 127.0.0.1:5173
- Click on Submit button, note the console message in the chrome inspector, but the cookie does NOT get saved

---

I want to set 'connect.sid' cookie of express-session in browser. In frontEnd I am using Vue 3.

I followed exactly everything should be added for the cookie to be saved. Maybe I am missing something. But I can't really figure out exactly what I am missing

here is my frontend code:

```
const submit = async () => {
  try {
    const { data } = await axios.post(
      "http://localhost:4050/new",
      { name: "Abeer" },
      { withCredentials: true }
    )

    console.log(data)
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error)
  }
}
```

here it's backend code:

```
const express = require("express")
const session = require("express-session")
const cors = require("cors")
const app = express()
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 4050
app.use(
  cors({
    origin: "http://127.0.0.1:5173",
    credentials: true,
  })
)
app.use(express.json())
app.use(
  session({
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false,
    secret: "session",
    cookie: {
      maxAge: 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000,
      sameSite: "none",
      secure: false,
    },
  })
)

// save a name as a cookie
app.post("/new", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const name = req.body.name
    req.session.name = name
    res.send({ message: "saves" }).status(201)
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error)
  }
})

app.get("/name", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    console.log(req.session.name)
    res.send({ message: req.session.name })
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error)
  }
})

app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Server is running on ${PORT}`))
```